# How to deploy a contract in Foundry?

Tags: solidity, foundry, forge, deploy

I want to deploy a smart contract using Foundry, but I don't want to pass my variables every time I run `forge create` inside of the terminal and I don't want to have to follow up every deployment with `forge verify-contract`.

Is there an easier way to deploy my contract, possibly using my `.env` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple different ways to deploy contracts in [Foundry](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry).

The most basic ones use `forge create` and require you to pass some *OPTIONS* in-line when you run the command.

Here is an example of deploying a contract called `NFT` on `Sepolia`, with a private key, using alchemy, and the contract is [verified on Etherscan](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xf61A4b67D8764a715E15a9392a869235BB81672c) on deployment after deployment.

```
forge create --private-key <PRIVATE_KEY> --rpc-url https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/<API_KEY> --constructor-args "NonFun" "NFT" --verify --etherscan-api-key <ETHERSCAN_API_KEY> NFT
```

Now if you want a more customizable and user-friendly version, Foundry has got you covered. This is where [Foundry scripting](https://book.getfoundry.sh/tutorials/solidity-scripting) comes into play. You can write entire deploy scripts that pull in variables straight from your `.env` file to redeploy more efficiently.

Here is an example of a script that [deploys the exact same contract](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x8426461dd2f33daaf2f24045aa4b715ade48d20d) with the same variables:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import {Script, console2} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {NFT} from "../src/NFT.sol";

contract NFTScript is Script {

    function run() public {
        vm.startBroadcast(vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY"));
        NFT nft = new NFT("NonFun", "NFT");
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}
```

The command to deploy the contract is now shortened to:

```
forge script NFTScript --rpc-url https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/<API_KEY> --verify --etherscan-api-key <ETHERSCAN_API_KEY> --broadcast
```

At present, I don't know of a way to pass the remaining in-line variables into the script, but I'm sure if one doesn't exist, Foundry will eventually add a way.

Of course, there are many more slightly different variations in the way you deploy your smart contracts, [here](https://book.getfoundry.sh/tutorials/solmate-nft) is a guide straight from the [Foundry book](https://book.getfoundry.sh/).